# Asp C# counter not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, counter

I am making a login function and I want to include a lockout when a user has entered incorrect information after 3 attempts it brings them to a blank panel and gets rid of the login portion. I am using a counter but it doesn't seem to work. If I enter incorrect info it would tell me I have entered wrong info but I won't get locked out

```
<asp:Panel ID="panel2" runat="server" Wrap="true" Visible="false">
        <h2 id="logError" runat="server" visible="false">Error logging in</h2>
        <strong>Username</strong><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="loginName"></asp:TextBox><br />
        <strong>Password</strong><asp:TextBox runat="server" TextMode="Password" ID="loginPass"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Return" OnClick="ReturnMain" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Log in" OnClick="login" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblInfo2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>

public void login(Object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        get_connection();
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE Email =@Email and Password = @Password", connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", loginName.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", loginPass.Text);
            //Session["User"] = loginName.Text;
            //Session["Number"] = attempt;
            int attempt = 0;


            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                //notification that the user has logged in
                YouHaveLoggedIn.Visible = true;
                panel1.Visible = false;
                panel2.Visible = false;
                panel6.Visible = true;
                WishPanel.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                attempt++;
                lblInfo2.Text = "Attempt count: " + attempt;

                logError.Visible = true;
                if (attempt >= 3) // lockout function but does not work, unsure why
                {
                    lockedOut.Visible = true;
                    panel2.Visible = false;
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            //user did not log in successfully
            lblInfo2.Text = "Error reading the database. ";
            lblInfo2.Text += err.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            //lblInfo.Text = "good connect. ";
            connection.Close();
        }

    }
```

I have lblInfo2 show me the attempt number but it always stays at 1. Is it a problem with my if else statement?

Comment: Where do you believe you're persisting `attempt` between requests?

Answer (score 0):

Your `attempt` variable is a local variable in your `login` method, which means the real number of attempts is always 0 everytime you try to log in, so the maximum attempts a user would get is 1.

You need to persist the number of attempts between requests, and you can do that with one of these ways:

1. Store the number of attempts per account (email) in the session (bad
   idea)
2. Store the number of attempts in the database (good idea)

If you choose 2. you might want to also save the datetime so that you can do something like: "After 30 minutes, the user can re-attempt login again".

Comment: I can't really edit the database to add an attempt part so I would have to use the session. If I were to use session, would it be something like this? Session["attempt"] = attempt;

Comment: More like: Session[Email + "#attempts"], in case the user tries another account (email)

Comment: the counter still stays at 5

Comment: you have to handle the clearing, store the Time too so that you check whether right now is a good time to reset them or not (Time Saved + 30 minutes < Now() = RESET)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create a new column in subscribers table which will hold the number of failed logins for the user?
The idea of putting the counter in session is bad because user can try a failed login and close the browser and login again with a new session. So every time the counter will get reset with every new session.
you need to store the counter of failed login somewhere (no sessions please).
Another bad approach is to store this counter in a text file.
Create a text file for each user on the server and put the counter of failed login in this text file and update it with every failed attempt.